# hadoop, python : command not running from script, neither fails, but runs fine from command line

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have a python program that runs the python commands

```
WARNING:root:executing - echo ~/Downloads/dw/hadoop_out/hadoop_out.2012-07-20 > /tmp/hadoop_load_file.tmp
WARNING:root:hadoop output file path written to /tmp/hadoop_load_file.tmp
WARNING:root:executing - /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -cat ~/Downloads/dw/proposalLoader_out/part-00000 > ~/Downloads/dw/hadoop_out/hadoop_out.2012-07-20
WARNING:root:hadoop path exists, removing - /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -test -d ~/Downloads/dw/proposalLoader_in
Deleted hdfs://master:54310/home/hduser/Downloads/dw/Loader_in
test: File does not exist: /home/hduser/Downloads/dw/Loader_out
WARNING:root:executing - /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir ~/Downloads/dw/proposalLoader_in
WARNING:root:executing - /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ~/Downloads/dw/load_input.txt ~/Downloads/dw/Loader_in
```

but when I see whats in `HDFS` i get nothing

```
$ hadoop dfs -ls ~/Downloads/dw/Loader_in
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hduser supergroup          0 2012-07-20 06:49 /home/hduser/Downloads/dw/Loader_in/load_input.txt
```

When I run the same command from `shell`, it executes and get the data in `HDFS`

```
$ /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal ~/Downloads/dw/load_input.txt ~/Downloads/dw/Loader_in

$ hadoop dfs -ls ~/Downloads/dw/Loader_in
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   3 hduser supergroup       2311 2012-07-20 06:50 /home/hduser/Downloads/dw/Loader_in
```

I am not sure why I am seeing this behavior, the code to execute the commands is as following

```
def execute(command):
    if not command:
        return (-1, 'command can not be empty or null')
    return subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
```